# Врач выписала или врач выписал? (если речь идёт о женщине)

Tags: согласование

Врач выписала или врач выписал? Доктор наук пришла или пришёл? (если речь идёт о женщине)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласование зависит от  ситуации. Врач рад, что больной поправился. Корректор исправил ошибки. Директор приглашен на совещание. В этих случаях неважен пол человека, мы его просто не уточняем.

В то же время в разговорной речи, в реальных ситуациях известный пол лица может быть обозначен: секретарь записала на прием, агроном уехала в город.

Поэтому возможны оба варианта: врач выписал и врач выписала. Сочетание "доктор наук пришел/пришла" вообще не очень корректно, здесь, как мне кажется, стилевая несовместимость.

Comment: Радиоведущая: "Напоминаю, что сегодня у нас в гостях БЫЛ кандидат педагогических наук Ирина Ивановна Иванова". Некорректная формулировка, я правильно поняла?

Comment: Мы с Вами рассматривали ситуацию, когда в предложении только нарицательное существительное, обозначающее лицо женского пола. Конечно, правильно будет : "Известный борец за права человека Анна Ивановна Иванова ОТМЕТИЛА свой юбилей". Но это связано с тем, что нарицательное существительное здесь является приложением, а согласование делается с подлежащим "Анна Ивановна Иванова". Во втором примере ошибка согласования не  так заметна: "был кандидат", но здесь также должно быть "была кандидат".

Answer (score 2):

Довольно часто приходится сталкиваться с просьбой помочь правильно согласовать сказуемое с подлежащим, выраженным личным существительным мужского рода, хотя речь идёт о женщине: начальник, юрист, врач, секретарь, бухгалтер и т. д.
... Наверное, следует прислушаться к советам ***К.С. Горбачевича: «...грамматическое согласование по мужскому роду («врач выписал рецепт», «секретарь позвонил» и т. д.) независимо от пола обозначаемого лица в наше время является безупречным***». И далее: «Итак, современная **литературная норма допускает оба способа согласования сказуемого с подлежащим в роде, если последнее обозначает женщину по её профессии, должности и т. п.** Правда, судя по материалам, смысловое согласование принадлежит сейчас главным образом разговорному стилю речи. Научной и тем более строго официальной речи такое согласование несвойственно».[Пётр Пустовалов. К вопросу о согласовании сказуемого с подлежащим](http://www.lych.ru/online/0ainmenu-65/37--s12009/275---)

При сочетании нарицательного существительного с собственным именем лица в роли подлежащего выступает последнее, и сказуемое согласуется с ним, например: Дежурный бригадир Оксана Литовченко проталкивалась к Захарову (Макаренко); ...Доверительно спросила санинспектор Фрося (П. Павленко).[Д.Э. Розенталь](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях род как раз и определяется по форме прош.вр. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с [[@Vera](/users/4440/vera)](/users/4440/vera).
В основном - определяется ситуацией.
Если делается акцент на человек как личности, то пол важен - и он передается в речи. Когда же речь держится в рамках профессионального или должностного контекста, пол субъекта не важен и он как правило уступает место согласованию по названию должности или профессии.

Примеры у [[@Vera](/users/4440/vera)](/users/4440/vera) это подтверждают.

> > В таких случаях род как раз и определяется по форме прош.вр. Или я что-то путаю?

А как тогда сама форма пр.в. определяется? )))

Знаете, как немцам русский язык объясняют? ***Чтобы понять какого пола заяц, надо его спугнуть. Если побежал - заяц. А если побежала - то зайчиха.***

Вот это примерно то, что вы предлагаете.