# «На кого-то более молодого». А как сказать о женщине?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, местоимения

*На кого-то более молодого.*
А как сказать о женском поле? На кого-то более молодую?

Comment: На какую-то более молодую. На кого-то, кто более молодая.

Comment: Но вообще род в русском языке и пол это вещи, служащие совершенно разным задачам. Поэтому и возникают дилеммы типа: "Вратарь отбила мяч/Вратарь отбил мяч." Все это должно разрешаться в пользу грамматики, а не в пользу смысла. Правильно: Вратарь отбил мяч/На кого-то более молодого. При этом имеется в виду женщины. Если на это надо долполнительно обратить внимание, тогда просто указывается дополнительными словами, что речь идет о женщине.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**У Розенталя** о согласовании **в числе и роде** таких местоимений со сказуемым:

При неопределенных и отрицательных местоимениях **некто, кто-то, никто** и др. сказуемое ставится в **единственном числе** (**в прошедшем времени глагола – в форме мужского рода, даже если речь идет о лице женского пола**), например: *Некто под инициалами A.M. (это оказалась корреспондентка одной из лондонских газет) писал следующее...; Кто-то из москвичек-конькобежек неудачно выступил на соревнованиях; Никто, даже лучшие спринтеры, не мог улучшить поставленный рекорд.*

Нетрудно заметить, что, если при таком местоимении есть прилагательное, оно употребляется в форме мужского рода:

Ср.: ***Словно дивною властью внушил ему кто-то странный там, у речной прохлады, эту новую любовь.*** [Ф. К. Сологуб. Капли крови (Навьи чары) (1905)]

***Недвижный кто-то, чёрный кто-то людей считает в тишине...*** [Блок]

В Вашем примере местоимение КТО-ТО употреблено с прилагательным МОЛОДОЙ:

***...кого-то более молодого.***

Или уберите местоимение КТО-ТО, тогда:

***на более молодую.***

Comment: Добавлю, что дело даже не в местоимениях. "Врач выписала рецепт" тоже не корректно в строгой речи. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45947/%d0%92%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%be-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5/46103#46103

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

***…на кого-нибудь помоложе.***

Comment: ‟ Кого-нибудь ” это тоже мужской род, если что.

Comment: _Jim Korbett: ‟ Кого-нибудь ” это тоже мужской род, если что._ ===   Зато «помоложе» не имеет рода – в отличие от «молодого».

Comment: Ну хорошо... ...

Answer (score 0):

Род — это не пол. Словами мужского рода зачастую обозначают лиц женского пола, — например, женщину-врача обозначают словом ‟ врач ”. Слово ‟ кого-то ” в данном предложении является винительным падежом слова ‟ кто-то ”. Словами ‟ кто ”, ‟ кто-то ” обозначают лиц женского пола, как и женщину-врача обозначают словом ‟ врач ”. Простейший пример: когда кто-то видит двух человек женского пола и говорит, обращаясь к одной из них: ‟ Кто это с тобой? ”
То есть слово ‟ кого-то ” можно говорить, обозначая человека женского пола, потому что, еще раз, род это не пол. И можно говорить ‟найти кого-то более молодого”, обозначая представителя женского пола, точно так же, как можно говорить ‟ выписал врач ” или ‟ хороший врач ”, обозначая врача-женщину.